# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin"

Tags: php, html

Desarrolle un plugin tipo system para Joomla 4. El plugin muestra dos formularios con shortcode y guarda datos en la base de datos. Al instalarlo todo va bien y se instala. Pero no renderiza los formularios, al entrar por la URL en produccion del archivo .php principal arroja lo siguiente:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin" not found in /home/andromed/newandro.andromedacomputer.net/plugins/system/pluginMicroservicios/pluginMicroservicios.php:31 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/andromed/newandro.andromedacomputer.net/plugins/system/pluginMicroservicios/pluginMicroservicios.php on line 31

En el localhost con XAMPP funciona bien, pero en produccion no

Cambie el codigo php a la version adecuado y ya no se que mas hacer

Comment: Hola. Puede que en producción te falten archivos, o que las rutas no sean las mismas. Revisa eso y nos dices.

Comment: ¿Qué tienes en la linea 31 de pluginMicroservicios.php?

Comment: Hola, revise las rutas y las cambie pero siguen, en produccion no tengo acceso. En la linea 31 declaro la clase PlgSystemPluginMicroservicios extends CMSPlugin

Comment: ¿En cuál espacio de nombres esta la clase `PlgSystemPluginMicroservicios`?